# Data type mismatch criteria expression "Joining between 3 tables"

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

[image]
I have 3 tables: suppliers, bills, and payments. Each supplier has payments and bills. I want to retrieve a report like this one:

> Supplier Name  |   total bills  |   total payments   |  balance

For a specific period that is specified by 2 `DateTimePickers`.

This my SQL query:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select c.sup_Name,c.sup_Place,sum(a.bill_Total),sum(d.pa_Value) 
from (suppliers c left JOIN bills a 
on c.sup_Id = a.bill_From) 
left join payments d on c.sup_Id = d.pa_To 
where (a.bill_Date >= '" + txbFrom.Text + "' and a.bill_Date <= '" + txbTo.Text + "') and (d.pa_EntryDate >= '" + txbFrom.Text + "' and d.pa_EntryDate <= '" + txbTo.Text + "') 
group by c.sup_Name,c.sup_Place order by c.sup_Name asc", objConn);

OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();// Here the error appear.
```

Comment: Use a parameterized query, but I'm pretty sure dates in MSAccess should be delimited with `#`, not '.

Comment: Is  there more information you could provide?

Comment: @ValAsensio , I added an image for relations

Comment: @RonBeyer, srry I said not, but it work :D .. (y)

Answer (score 0):

For `MySQL` I had to convert the date: `dt = DateTime` which can easily be extracted from the `DateTimePicker`.

```
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Also note that unless the time is also specified, the time defaults to 00:00:00, so if checking for <= you may need to set the time to 23:59:59 first. I used extension methods for both.

Comment: I found the solution, thank you for your help, just  #date#  instead of   'date'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't format the parameters into an SQL string: instead use `OleDbParameter` to do this for you (and help avoid SQL injection attacks).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx